# Python changing part of each line in a file

Tags: python

I am learning python and I am trying to write a code that allows me to read in a file, then change a portion of each line in a text file, and the output is written to the file.

Each line in the file has different years and information in it.

What I have so far is:

```
filein = input('file.txt', 'r')  

for line in filein:
    str = "1984 - 2000" 
        print str.replace("1984 - 2000", "1970 - 2010")

file.close()
```

When I try this I get this error "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

How can I fix/ improve this code?

Comment: What's `file`? You must define it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
filein = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = filein.read()

for line in lines:
    str = "1984 - 2000" 
    print (line.replace(str, "1970 - 2010"))

filein.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to put parenthesis around what your printing. Also change str to line and 1984-2000 to str. Like this:

```
print (line.replace(str, "1970 - 2010"))
```

Comment: FWIW, assigning to str overrides the builtin str.  Better to use string or at least str_.