# How do you insert a column into an existing csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm a complete newb to Python and need some direction on how to go about inserting a column into an existing csv file with data=today's date included.

I would appreciate any guidance/insight you may provide.

Thank you in advance!
AJ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python changing part of each line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062436/python-changing-part-of-each-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Read each line, add the field you want, write it out to a new file.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.  How do you add the field?  I know how to read the line and write it out but not familiar with how to add the field and also its location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a little background search on working with csv's in Python.  There is a bunch of good articles / tutorials.  Most use the `csv` module as a convenience and for features, but it isn't necessary.

The basic schema to modify (as suggested above in comments) is to:

- open the file you want to read
- open another file that will hold the modified results
- walk through the file being read line-by-line
- either compute the new value if you need to, or just append it to the line
- write it to the new file
- close both files

Here is an example using `csv` module:

```
import csv
input_file = 'data.csv'
output_file = 'data_mod.csv'

with open(output_file, 'w') as target:
    target_writer = csv.writer(target)

    # open the source
    with open(input_file, 'r') as source:
        source_reader = csv.reader(source)
        # now both are "open and ready"
        # fix the header row, assuming there is one by reading 1 line
        header = source_reader.__next__()
        # csv reader returns a list for the rows read, so header is a list,
        # we can just add to it
        header.append('sum')
        # write to the modified file
        target_writer.writerow(header)
        # now use loop to update all remaining rows
        for row in source_reader:
            sum = int(row[0]) + int(row[1])
            row.append(sum)
            target_writer.writerow(row)
# if you use the 'with' command structure, it will close the files automatically
print('done')
```

The original file:

```
value 1,value 2
1,2
3,4
-2,2
```

the modified file, data_mod.csv:

```
value 1,value 2,sum
1,2,3
3,4,7
-2,2,0
```

Comment: Jeff, thank you very much!  This helped a lot.  The only thing is I'm getting an additional row prior to the append and I was wondering if there is a way to have the column append at the beginning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "getting an additional row prior to the append".  One thing to note is that when you can use the `next` method I showed above to "burn" lines you don't want in the file being read.  Not sure how your orig file is set up.  And on point of appending at beginning of the row, if you use `csv` the read results are lists as I showed above.  So, use standard list methods such as `insert` to put the new stuff in wherever you want.  And of course, if this answers your question, accept the answer.  :)

Comment: I'm very new to all of this in Python but I think I understand what you are saying and will continue to work through. Thanks again, Jeff.